# Weird layouting Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very familiar with layouts on Android but I cannot explain this one:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mask_for_not_authenticated"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notLoggedTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You are not logged in, you haven't any profile to be shown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notLoggedTV"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="What? How is it possible?! I want to be in!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Of course, it looks the same on the device and the floating button is not in the layout. And TextView is in the middle.

Why is the result not centered? I have tried `layout_centerInParent` and also to put nothing (to let `gravity=center` do) as well, without success.

Comment: The only anomaly I can see is the extra **+** here `android:layout_below="@+id/notLoggedTV"`. But maybe this `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` interferes with the parent's `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: That's how I do not to have problems at Runtime because the view you refer to is not created, very useful trick btw. But nope, doesn't change anything

Comment: `the view you refer to is not created` Wrong: I can see it **is** already created (just above the Button). If the TextView was declared **below** the Button, then yes, you would be right.

Comment: Yes, you're perfectly right but the practice I'm used to and it works is always to do like this and I recommend you that for the complicated the layouts

Comment: I recommend declaring first the referred Views and not using `anticipated referencing`. Points of View. What about the `centering` comment? Did you overlook it?

Comment: There are a lot of confusing answers below. Just so I get this right, the issue is that the `Button` isn't centred horizontally in the parent right? Maybe make this extra clear in the question if that's the case.

Comment: just remove gravity in Relativelayout and add centerinparent in TextView

Comment: Yes that's I've done at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change TextView width to match parrent and set gravity to center

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mask_for_not_authenticated"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notLoggedTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="You are not logged in, you haven't any profile to be shown" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/notLoggedTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="What? How is it possible?! I want to be in!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try add this in your TextView `android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" `   and your button `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Comment: Did you read the question: I mean, I know how it works and I already tried that...

Comment: I found a solution, not that far from your suggestion, I'll modify it and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notLoggedTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="You are not logged in, you haven't any profile to be shown" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="What? How is it possible?! I want to be in!" />
```

Remove the `android:gravity="center"` from the `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: That's better but do you have an explanation why the `TextView`disappeared... ? o_O

Answer (score 0):

You have redundancies in your code. Your parent has gravity set to center, so you do not need to have any position tags in your children for it to center properly.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/mask_for_not_authenticated"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notLoggedTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="You are not logged in, you haven't any profile to be shown" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/notLoggedTV"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="What? How is it possible?! I want to be in!" />
```

Comment: I hate quoting myself: `and also to put nothing (to let gravity=center do)` Already tried your solution, but nice try!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired center affect. I didn't see that this was in a RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/mask_for_not_authenticated"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notLoggedTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="You are not logged in, you haven't any profile to be shown" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/notLoggedTV"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/notLoggedTV"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="What? How is it possible?! I want to be in!" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove gravity:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mask_for_not_authenticated"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/notLoggedTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="You are not logged in, you haven't any profile to be shown" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notLoggedTV"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="What? How is it possible?! I want to be in!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```